# IllegalArgumentException while creating property key in scala gremlin

Tags: scala, cassandra, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I am trying to create schema with the property keys defined for my keys used as properties in vertices and edges.

```
mgmt.makePropertyKey(ID_).dataType(classOf[String]).cardinality(Cardinality.SET).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey("age").dataType(classOf[Integer]).cardinality(Cardinality.SET).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey("size").dataType(classOf[Integer]).cardinality(Cardinality.SET).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey("time").dataType(classOf[Long]).cardinality(Cardinality.SET).make()
```

**age** , **size** , **time** will be property keys in the edges.

Getting the below exception while creating keys,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a supported data type: long

**Time** property key will be long value since i am current timemillsecs in that.

Same this works when i change to

```
mgmt.makePropertyKey("time").dataType(classOf[String]).cardinality(Cardinality.SET).make()
```

If i do that it is creating problem during graph traversal for time check. Getting some classcast exception. I couldnot give a long value to compare the time

Am i doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It works with **java.lang.Long** datatype

```
 mgmt.makePropertyKey(TIME).dataType(classOf[java.lang.Long]).cardinality(Cardinality.SET).make()
```